# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program when changing code in a running project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an on-again/off-again issue with all of my VS2010 projects, while I'm running the code in Debug Mode (x86), if I change ANY code in the project while I'm in break mode, as soon as I start running the project again, once the code I changed starts to run I get the "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program error".

This had been happening for weeks, and then over the last month is seemed to correct itself and I could run and change code anywhere in the project in break mode without error and continue to run with the new code being recognized, but for the last week anytime I want to change *any* code I have to stop the project, change the code, start the project.

I've tried the obvious things like rebooting my computer, running only one VS2010 project at a time, but I'm hoping this won't require a re-install of VS2010.

Any ideas if there is some sort of setting that I need to change in the project, or an option in VS to get around this?

Comment: A question like this needs to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: I have Microsoft Security Essentials running on a Windows 7 machine with 200GB of drive space available and 32GB of RAM with no paging file.

Comment: I tracked down the source of the problem.  My project somehow had a reference back to its own compiled EXE in the references list.  While I was going through the references in the project I noticed it there, removed it, and now I can change code on the fly again.